# How to get csv all number in the list

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I'm playing Python csv for fun and not using pandas library. I try to split a column to get the number, the column contains the alphabet and number. I successfully get the number but not all. There have one is missing.

There have only two types of data in the column which is

```
GL Code : 8500/000
GL Code : 850/000
```

Here is my code

```
csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
list_1 = list(csv_reader)

for line in list_1:

    coa_name = line[0]
    split_coa_code = coa_name.split('GL Code : ')

    print (split_coa_code)
```

Result

```
['', '8500/000']
['books']
['books2']
['', '850/000']
['fish']
```

Expected Result example

```
8500/000
850/000
8600/000
```

Comment: As a heads up,`//` is not a valid comment, `#` is. `//` is integer divide

Comment: Please write python. use `line.split(":")` and access the resulting list for your data. or maybe its `line[0].split(":")`  It is totally unclear to me how you come from  850/000 to 8600/000 - noting in your inputdata reflects that. Question is unclear. Datastructure is unclear. Problem is unclear. Show some line of your real data and post a [mcve] that we can run using your data to replicate your problem.

Comment: @PatrickArtner I edited the code. But how could I get the second value and delete the unused data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sould work:

```
for line in list_1:
    if 'GL Code :' in line:
        print(line.replace('GL Code : ', ''))
```

Comment: There will be nothing if use `GL Code :` because the column is `GL Code : 8500/000`.

Comment: No. It will replace ```GL Code : ``` with ```''``` and return the remains of the line, that is, in this case ```8500/000```.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    list_1 = list(csv_reader)

    for line in list_1:

        split_coa_code = line.split(':')[1]

        print (split_coa_code)
```

Comment: I got this error: IndexError: list index out of range

Answer (score 0):

This should work for your problem.

```
csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
list_1 = list(csv_reader)

for line in list_1:

    coa_name = line[0]

    if not coa_name:
        # if empty string at that line
        continue

    split_coa_code = coa_name.split(': ')[-1]

    print(split_coa_code)
```

At `coa_name.split(': ')[-1]` it will return `["GL Code : ", "8500/000"]` or `["GL Code : ", "850/000"]` based on your sample inputs.

I am splitting at `": "` that way you will be returned a list containing 2 items. The second item in the list is what you are looking for. Hence, I am using a negative index i.e. `[-1]` to get the last element.

**Note** - It will be of type string

Let me know in case you have any questions.